# C++ copy constructor clear up on vector<Base*> of Derived*

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, derived-class, base-class

I have a class which uses a class of base pointers to derived objects, so I need to have my own desructor for deleting the vector's elements and custom copy and assignment funcitons. I'm not entirely sure about the preferred way of implementing a structure like below and writing the right copy and assignment constructors and destructors for it. May I ask you to guide me? I've read a lot and searched but I'm still not sure.

```cpp
class Base 
{
   public:
   Base();
   ~virtual Base();

   int a;
   int type; // Derived1 or Derived2
   std::string b;
   ...
}

class Derived1 : public Base 
{
public:
    Derived1();
    Derived1(const Base* a);
    virtual ~Derived1();
}

class Derived1 
{
    Derived1::Derived1(const Base *a) : Base(a) 
    {

    }
}

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2();
    Derived2(const Base* a);
    virtual ~Derived2();

    std::string d1;
    std::string d2;
    int d3;
}

class Derived2 
{
    Derived2::Derived2(const Base *a) : Base(a) {
        this->d1 = ((Derived2*)a)->d1;
        this->d2 = ((Derived2*)a)->d2;
        this->d3 = ((Derived2*)a)->d3;
    }
}


class A 
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    A(const A& a);
    A& operator = (const A& a);

    std::string someString;
    std::vector<Base*> vect;
}

A::~A() {
    std::vector<Base*>::iterator it = vect.begin();
    while (it != vect.end()) {
        delete (*it);
        it++;
}

A::A(const A &a)
{
    someString = a.someString;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < a.vect.size(); ++i {
        someString = a.someString;
        Base* base = a.vect.at(i);
        if(base->type == base::TypeD1) {
            base = new Derived1( a.vect.at(i) );
            vect.push_back( base );
        }
        else {
            base = new Derived2( a.vect.at(i) );
            vect.push_back( base );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use smart pointers http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: The `class Derived1 { ... }` around member function definitions don't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop in the destructor is fine in practice, and is the
usual solution.  Formally, it is undefined behavior, since you
are leaving objects in the vector (pointers to deleted objects)
which aren't copiable, but in practice: the vector won't copy
them unless you resize it to something bigger, or insert or
erase on it.  If you really want to avoid the undefined
behavior:

```
for ( auto current = vect.begin(); current != vect.end(); ++ current ) {
    Base* tmp = *it;
    *it = nullptr;
    delete tmp;
}
```

But this is one case where I probably wouldn't bother (and
I tend to be more sensitive to undefined behavior than most).

Comment: That's UB even though the vector's destructor is called immediately after?

Comment: Thank you! I've added code for copy constructor, Valgrind reported no memory leak so far.

Comment: @aschepler Formally, yes.  There are uncopiable objects in the vector.  Practically... no implementation is going to copy the pointer unless you do something like `insert` or `erase` (and of course, implementations where copying it will cause problems are very, very rare---if any still exist).

Comment: @cmaster Sorry, but any lvalue to rvalue conversion of a pointer to deleted memory is undefined behavior.  (I even know of one implementation where it would fail, many, many years back.)

Comment: Now you got me curious: Can you point me to the part of the standard that makes this UB? And which is the implementation that would fail?

Comment: @cmaster 
For the standard: §3.7.4.2/4: "If the argument given to
a deallocation function in the standard library is a pointer
that is not the null pointer value (4.10), the deallocation
function shall deallocate the storage referenced by the pointer,
rendering invalid all pointers referring to any part of the
deallocated storage. The effect of using an invalid pointer
value (including passing it to a deallocation function) is
undefined."  And assignment or copy requires the _value_ of the right hand argument.

Comment: @cmaster As for the implementation on which it would fail is
easy: the one I saw was on an 80286, where the implementation of
`malloc` always got memory from the OS, in a new segment, the
implementation of `free` returned it to the OS (which unmapped
the segment), and copying a pointer involved loading the segment
register, which would trigger a trap if the segment wasn't
mapped.

Comment: Thanks, I'll delete my first comment then. I'm sure glad that I'm too young to have witnessed the insanities of segmented memory...

Answer (score 1):

First, do you actually need to copy and assign objects of type `A`?  If no, the simple solution is:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;

    // ...
};
```

If yes, then you want some polymorphic way of copying the elements of the vector.  (Any time at all you have `if (b->type == Base::TypeD1) { do_this(); } else { do_that(); }`, stop and think if it would make sense to add a virtual function for `do_this`/`do_that`.  The else-if-heimer's way doesn't allow for future new derived classes; the virtual way does.)

```
class Base
{
public:
    // ...
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
    // ...
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Derived1* clone() const;
};

Derived1* Derived1::clone() const {
    return new Derived1(*this);
}
```

The copy assignment operator of `A` will need to destroy the old contents of the lhs, just like the destructor, and then copy the new contents over, just like the copy constructor.  So let's put those two operations in private functions:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    A(const A&);
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&);
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;

    // ...
private:
    void destroy_contents();
    void copy_from(const std::vector<Base*>& v);
};

void A::destroy_contents() {
    std::vector<Base*>::iterator it = vect.begin();
    while (it != vect.end()) {
        delete (*it);
        ++it;
    }
    vect.clear();
}

void A::copy_from(const std::vector<Base*>& v) {
    std::vector<Base*>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
    while (it != v.end()) {
        vect.push_back((*v)->clone());
        ++it;
    }
}

A::~A() { destroy_contents(); }

A::A(const A& a) :
    someString(a.someString),
    vect()
{
    copy_from(a.vect);
}

A& A::operator=(const A& a) {
    if (this != &a) {
        someString = a.someString;
        destroy_contents();
        copy_from(a.vect);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a vector of any pointer type, the vector does not know anything about the type behind the pointer, nor does it care: The vector operates on the pointers *only*, copying them to a new location if need be, but never even touching the objects themselves. As such, it is your responsibility to destroy the objects themselves.

As James Kanze points out, there is a slight danger of undefined behavior when handling invalidated pointers. However, since the `vector` is not used in any way after deleting the objects it holds, no undefined behavior is invoked in the code you've given (the vector won't need to reallocate its memory so it won't need to assign invalidated pointers, and destruction of pointers is a noop). As such, your destructor of `class A` is perfectly fine.

The copy constructor of `class A`, however, is unnecessarily complicated and an ample source of errors (it needs to be updated whenever a new derived class is defined!). The best way to do this is to use a `clone()` function:

```
class Base {
    public:
        //...
        virtual Base* clone() const = 0;    //Returns a new copy of the object. Pure virtual if the Base class is abstract.
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    public:
        Derived1(const Derived& a);
        virtual Derived* clone() const {
            return new Derived1(*this);
        }
};
```

If you make `clone()` pure virtual in the base class, you have the guarantee that your compiler will complain if you forget to implement it in any derived class. With that, the copy constructor of `class A` is next to trivial:

```
A::A(const A &a) {
    someString = a.someString;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < a.vect.size(); ++i {
        vect.push_back(a.vect[i]->clone());
    }
}
```